# VC++6 thread safe static initialization

Tags: c++, multithreading, static-initialization

I'll start off by saying that I'm already aware that in C++11 standard, static local initialization is now threadsafe.  However, I am still required to maintain compatibility with Microsoft Visual C++ 6, so C++11 behavior isn't applicable.

I have a static library which uses a handful of static variables.  I ran into issues with static variables getting used before they were initialized (single threaded):

```
class A
{
private:
    static A Instance;
public:
    static A& GetInstance() { return Instance; }
};

// And then from a different file:

A.GetInstance();
```

A.GetInstance() would return an uninitialized instance.  So I followed this advice http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use-members.html and moved all my static variables into local methods.

```
class A
{
public:
    static A& GetInstance()
    {
        static A Instance;
        return Instance;
    }
};
```

I thought that fixed the problem, but now I'm finding out that stuff isn't always getting initialized properly because I create other threads during startup.

Raymond Chen described the problem in 2004:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040308-00/?p=40363 , but nobody seemed to have any solutions.  The only solutions anyone mentions are to use mutexes to prevent initialization from multiple threads.  But this seems like a chicken and egg problem.  Every type of mutex that I'm aware of requires some kind of initialization before it can be used.  How can I make sure it gets initialized before I use it for the first time.  I guess I'd have to make it static local.  But how do I ensure it get initialized from one thread?

If I could ensure that I have one memory location initialized to a known value before anything else is initialized, I could use interlocked operations on it to spin wait to bootstrap my whole initialization.  Is there any way to ensure one memory location is in a known state from multiple threads before any other initialization occurs?  Or any kind of synchronization that can be done without the chicken and egg problem?

Comment: That's not an option.  I'm writing plugins for a commercial application compiled with VC++ 6.  It has to use the exact same compiler to be compatible.

Comment: The not-so-obvious solution would be to take a grip on the lifetime of the variables. That is completely abandon dynamic initialization stage together with static local variables and always initialize everything explicitly.

Comment: Are you okay with using a static global variable?  You could have `static A & initialize = A::GetInstance();` right after the class so you know the function is called and the object is initialized before anything else happens.

Comment: @NathanOliver The problem is, any file which uses A::GetInstance() could be the first one to call it.  But I think that does point me in the right direction.  If I ensure every file which needs to use A::GetInstance() calls it once to initialize before doing anything else, including any initializers which start threads, then I don't have to worry about something not getting initialized before a background thread uses it.

Comment: @VTT I can't really imagine completely getting rid of statics completely.  I need at least 1 to share state across the process, and having 1 vs. many doesn't really change the problem.

Comment: I haven't written to abandon statics completely, I only suggest to explicitly initialize them before first use happens. Though I guess this approach can not be used in your situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution to this problem is to use a static object that can be zero-initialized or constant-initialized combined with atomic operations to "bootstrap" yourself into a position where you can call more complex initialization safely.

Zero and constant initialization is guaranteed to happen before non-constant initialization and since it effectively happens simultaneously it doesn't rely on order of initialization.

### Use a Lazy-Initialized Object

A very simple example would use a zero-initialized pointer to the global static instance, that indicates if the static has been initialized, like so:

```
class A
{
private:
    volatile static A* Instance;  // zero-initialized to NULL
public:
    static A& GetInstance() {
        A* inst = Instance;
        if (!inst) {
            A* inst = new Instance(...);
            A* cur = InterlockedCompareExchange(&Instance, newInst, 0);
            if (cur) {
              delete inst;
              return *cur;
            }
        }
        return *inst;
    }
};
```

The downside of the above approach is that two (or more) one `A` object might be created, if two (or more) threads both initially see `A::Instance` as null. The code correctly selects only one `A` object to be the true static global returned to all callers and the others are simply silently deleted, but this may be a problem when it isn't even possible to create more than one `Instance` object in a process (e.g., because it backed by some fundamentally singleton resource, perhaps a handle to some hardware resource). There is also be some wasted work if more than one `Instance` is created, which might matter if the creation process is expensive.

This pattern is sometimes called *racy single-check*.

### Use a Lazy-Initialized Mutex

A better solution that avoids the above pitfalls would be to use a mutex to guard the creation of the singleton. Of course, now mutex initialization has the same ordering problem, but we can use the above trick to fix that (and we know it's OK to create more than one mutex object).

```
class MutexHolder
{
private:
    volatile static CRITICAL_SECTION* cs;  // zero-initialized to NULL
public:
    static CRITICAL_SECTION* get() {
        A* inst = cs;
        if (!inst) {
            CRITICAL_SECTION* inst = new CRITICAL_SECTION();
            InitializeCriticalSection(inst);
            CRITICAL_SECTION* cur = InterlockedCompareExchange(&cs, newInst, 0);
            if (cur) {
              DeleteCriticalSection(inst);
              delete inst;
              return *cur;
            }
        }
        return *inst;
    }
};

class A
{
private:
    static MutexHolder mutex;
    static A* Instance;  // zero-initialized to NULL
public:
    static A& GetInstance() {
        A* inst;
        CRITICAL_SECTION *cs = mutex.get();
        EnterCriticalSection(cs);
        if (!(inst = Instance)) {
            inst = Instance = new A(...);
        }
        EnterCriticalSection(cs);
        return inst;
    }
};
```

Here the `MutexHolder` is a re-usable wrapper around the Windows `CRITICAL_SECTION` object which performs lazy and thread-safe initialization inside the `get()` method, and can be zero-initialized. This `MutexHolder` is then used as a classic mutex to protect the creation of the static `A` object inside `A::GetInstance`.

You can make `GetInstance` faster at the cost of some complexity with the use of [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking): rather than getting the `CRITICAL_SECTION` unconditionally, first check if `Instance` is set (like the first example) and then return it directly if it is.

### InitOnceExecuteOnce

Finally, if you are targeting Windows Vista or later, Microsoft has added a ready-made tool which handles this directly: [InitOnceExecuteOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683493(v=vs.85).aspx). You can find an [worked example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686934(v=vs.85).aspx). This is approximately analogous POSIX's to `pthead_once` and works because initialization is performed using the constant `INIT_ONCE_STATIC_INIT`.

In your case it would look something like:

```
INIT_ONCE g_InitOnce = INIT_ONCE_STATIC_INIT;
A* g_AInstance = 0;  

BOOL CALLBACK MakeA(
    PINIT_ONCE InitOnce,       
    PVOID Parameter,           
    PVOID *lpContext)
{
    g_AInstance = new A(...);
    return TRUE;
}

class A
{
private:

public:
    static A& GetInstance() {
        // Execute the initialization callback function 
        bStatus = InitOnceExecuteOnce(&g_InitOnce,          
                            MakeA,   
                            NULL,                 
                            NULL);          
        assert(bStatus);
        return *g_AInstance;
    }
};
```

Raymond Chen wrote a [blog entry about this function](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120420-00/?p=7813) which also makes for good reading.

Comment: Is the constant initialization guarantee universal in C++?  I'm trying to figure out how to verify this behavior to my own satisfaction before making large scale changes that depend on it.

Comment: You also you need to check compiler extensions to ensure that `volatile` can be used when a memory barrier is required. _"This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution,..."_ from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: @RichardCritten - indeed, but with VC6 your options are limited since this is before the memory model days and AFAIK even before VS started treated volatile specially with respect to threading. In any case, the second solution doesn't make any such assumptions since it simply passes the object into the `Interlocked` methods, which work find (and evidently are a MS-specific API outside of the the C++ spec).

Comment: @BryceWagner - yes, it is guaranteed and heavily relied on. In practice, it is baked right into the executable format: e.g., the `.bss` and `.data` sections in executables contain, _on disk_, the actual values of zero and constant-initialized variables so spring into being already initialized as soon as the process starts - in a way they are essentially perpetually initialized! See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables) for more details.

Comment: Another problem with your first solution (`class A`) is the lack of memory ordering. Another thread may use the new object while it is still under construction

Comment: @curiousguy12 - in theory yes, in practice on VC6 with `volatile` no (generally OK even without volatile). This was a more-or-less endorsed pattern to do double checked locking. Note that the variable is only swapped in after initialization and using `InterlockedCompareExchange` which is both a compiler and hardware barrier. Note that you can't really argue this from a standards PoV since C++ was silent on threads in the VC6 era (far before C++11) and so "what the platform does is practice" is kind of the only peg you can hang your hat on.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot.. `volatile` on VC is stronger than usual

Comment: If you want to be totally safe, you can do the initial read `A* inst = Instance;` with `InterlockedExchangeAdd(..., 0)` instead, but a plain read was common in practice.

Comment: @curiousguy12 - yes, Visual Studio for some range of versions gave `volatile` _release_ semantics much like the Java memory model does. Recent versions do not as they have adopted the C++ `atomic` classes as the preferred way to get this effect. VS6 didn't do this either: you won't get barriers using `volatile` in VS6. Still, you don't need a barrier for this read: you just need the compiler not to do anything crazy and VS6 doesn't. For example, the "double checked locking" pattern "just works" on x86 if the compiler doesn't do anything unusual due to the strong memory model in x86.

Comment: ... and the code above has weaker requirements even than double checked locking. Now I'm not one to generally advise stuff that "seems to work but isn't guaranteed by the standard", especially when it comes to concurrency, but we have limited options in a pre-C++11 world. In any case, 2 of the 3 options above don't really rely on any assumptions about compiler or hardware behavior.